# iOS Mapkit get directions works in Playground , but not in app update:

Tags: ios, swift, get, google-play, directions

Here's a simple app with a VC that asks for directions from MapKit.  It compiles and executes, but doesn't work properly.  Below is the complete code, followed by the log results:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  MapKitDirections
//

import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func getDistance() {
        let source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(
            coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-41.27, 173.28), addressDictionary: nil))
        let destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(
            coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-41.11, 173), addressDictionary: nil))

        let directionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        directionsRequest.source = source
        directionsRequest.destination = destination

        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)

        print("before: directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler")
        directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler({(response, error) in
            print("\nwithin: completion handler\n")
            print("\n error: \(error)")
            print("\n response: \(response?.routes.first?.distance)")
        })
        print("after: directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler\n")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getDistance()
    }
}


before: directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler
after: directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler

2015-07-03 21:32:09.536 MapKitDirections[293:69261] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2015-07-03 21:32:09.541 MapKitDirections[293:69261] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
2015-07-03 21:32:09.545 MapKitDirections[293:69218] PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo=0x12f660710 {_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x12f713a00 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.", NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/directions.arpc, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/directions.arpc, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}

within: completion handler


 error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo=0x12f660710 {_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x12f713a00 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.", NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/directions.arpc, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/directions.arpc, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3})

 response: nil
```

This question was previously posted as "iOS Mapkit get directions works in Playground , but not in app".  but @matt wanted to see the code within an app instead of a Playground.

Admittedly, this is a very simple app -- that does nothing but attempt to get directions.  I did it this way to focus on the issue and avoid the distraction of unnecessary code.

FWIW, the same code executed in a Playground returns the directions, as shown in the original post.

Comment: I'm trying to get directions and the same thing happened to me.

Error: "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
Response = nil

Comment: Remarkably similar to this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7160

Comment: So this is iOS 9 beta? It would have been useful to mention that in your question. SSL communication rules have greatly changed in iOS 9...

Comment: @matt Yeah, it is a repost of the forum thread, and iOS 9 beta -- I didn't want to emphasize that ...  I figured the SSL rules had changed, but as you can determine by the code, print statements, and error messages, I don't participate in any SSL interface.  The error/failure is caused when the completionHandler is initiated --  directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler({(response, error) in ...

Comment: Right, but clearly the change in the SSL rules is crucial here. You _might_ try turning off the new requirements with the allow-all info.plist setting... And file a bug! This is exactly the sort of thing Apple wants to know about.